# How do I change my monitor's gamma settings?

Tags: colors, gui, monitors, setuptools

How do I change my laptop monitor's gamma settings on Linux Mint 9 (preferably using a GUI interface)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X11 can adjust gamma with the command xgamma, which should come standard with X11 on most Linux distros.  This works independent of what monitor you use.

The proprietary drivers for some graphics cards offer GUI gamma adjustments.

Comment: Do you know what driver I am using? inxi -G
Graphics:  
Card Intel Mobile 945GM/GMS 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller 
X.Org 1.7.6 Res: 1280x800@60.0hz 
GLX Renderer Mesa DRI Intel 945GM GEM 20091221 2009Q4 x86/MMX/SSE2 
GLX Version 1.4 Mesa 7.7.1

Comment: Thank you . Just looking at the man page for xgamma I found what I was looking for called xvidtune.